# Accessibility on Tabview cause resetting tab

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, swiftui-tabview

I'm using TabView to have a simple onboarding contents. It seems like when voiceOver is enabled and tabview get the focus binding variable automatically will reset to 0.
here is sample app I made for this issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Header")
            TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                ForEach((0...2), id: \.self) { index in
                    Button {
                        selectedIndex += 1
                    } label: {
                        Text("at: \(selectedIndex), Goto Next Tab")
                    }
                    .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
            Text("Footer")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I used accessibility inspector to check behaviour and here is the result

[image: Before Focus]
[image: After Focus]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on iOS simulator. Do you have any more specifications? And can you embed a gif of the issue?